# Search document by id very slow

Tags: solr, cassandra, solandra

my documents has an id field, called "doc_id", declared with the following attributes:

```
<field name="doc_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

This id is marked as an unique key with the  tag.

I try to load many documents at once, giving their ids in request f.e. doc_id:(235, 163, 256, ..., 10473)

The count of identifiers in the query is never greater than 100. However, the more documents are there in the storage the longer it takes for this query to execute. I thought this would be something like the SQL query f.e. "select doc where doc_id in (...)" but with index on "doc_id" the execution time should be constant, shouldn't it? So why is it slowing down in solandra after I add more and more docs?

I'm working with Solandra (Solr 3.4 + Cassandra 1.0.3)

Regards, T

Answer (score 2):

Use [RealTimeGet](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/RealTimeGet) (Solr >= 4.0).

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/get?ids=1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

As the ids are unique do not search over it. The search performance will always be slower.
Try to use filter queries e.g. `fq=doc_id:235`
This would allow Solr to use [filtercache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache) and giving you a much improved performance.

Comment: I tried the two options:
**1.** `q=doc_id:("...", "..."...)`
**2.** `q=*:*&fq=doc_id:("...", "...", ...)` - this is **50%** slower.

Any Ideas, how to improve performance when search by id

Comment: Solr 4.10 and Heliosearch .07 have added a terms query (or terms filter) to more efficiently match many terms in a single field. http://yonik.com/solr-terms-query/